# ggplot2 : plotting the time at which events happen

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe `df` that looks like this :

```
Date        Heure    Event
2017-06-16  08:15    A
2017-06-16  08:20    B
2017-06-16  08:21    B
2017-06-16  10:12    A
2017-06-17  07:10    B
2017-06-17  07:15    A
2017-06-17  08:00    A
2017-06-17  08:45    A
```

How could I plot the total number of events, depending on the time of the day or the date, using `ggplot2`?

If I dot a simple `plot(df$Heure)` I get a working result, but I'd like to use `ggplot2` since it's more customizable. I've looked around, but explanations like [this one](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/32-r-graphics-essentials/128-plot-time-series-data-using-ggplot/) or [that one](https://www.r-bloggers.com/plotting-time-series-data-using-ggplot2/) need something to plot on the y-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like the following?

```
ggplot(my_data, aes(Date)) +
  geom_bar()
```

[image]

```
ggplot(my_data, aes(Heure)) +
  geom_bar()
```

[image]

```
ggplot(my_data, aes(Date, fill = Event)) +
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge())
```

[image]

Comment: YES ! Thank you very much :)